# TFS 2013 - Default Build Definition Template Throwing This Error on "Queue new Build

Tags: msbuild

Below is the error description what seeing once tried to Queue my build definition. Any clue would be appreciated.

> 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)   The build process failed validation.
>   Details:   Validation Error: The private implementation of activity
>   '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler
>   error(s) encountered processing expression "logFileDropLocation". 
>   'logFileDropLocation' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to
>   its protection level.
>
> Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1:
>   DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Compiler
>   error(s) encountered processing expression "If
>   (platformConfiguration.IsEmpty    Or
>   BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations.Count = 1,
>   BuildDropProvider.CombinePaths(DropLocation, "logs"), If
>   (platformConfiguration.IsPlatformEmptyOrAnyCpu,
>   BuildDropProvider.CombinePaths(DropLocation, "logs",
>   platformConfiguration.Configuration),
>   BuildDropProvider.CombinePaths(DropLocation,    "logs",
>   platformConfiguration.Platform,
>   platformConfiguration.Configuration)))".  Reference to a non-shared
>   member requires an object reference.  Reference to a non-shared member
>   requires an object reference.  'DropLocation' is not declared. It may
>   be inaccessible due to its protection level.  Reference to a
>   non-shared member requires an object reference.  'DropLocation' is not
>   declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. 
>   'DropLocation' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.
>
> An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop
>   location. Details: Internal Server Error

Below is the Workflow view

[image: Workflow View]

It seems I may need to add a "logFileDropLocation" inside my build template. My template XAML has something like

```
<Assign x:TypeArguments="x:String"    DisplayName="Initialize LogFile Drop Location" To="[logFileDropLocation]"
```

But not sure how to add logFileDropLocation value here and how to get rid of this error

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Uninstall and installed the correct version would done this. I am not remembering the exact version issue.